# PHP Post on Bootstrap submitHandler

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, post

I'm pretty new in web development and I know this might sound like a very simple question but I'm trying to add a login functionality in a bootstrap template.

The .js with the template validates the contents of the text and such. I'm trying to add a POST function in the submitHandler.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
 $('#login-form').validate({

                focusInvalid: false, 
                ignore: "",
                rules: {
                    txtusername: {
                        minlength: 2,
                        required: true
                    },
                    txtpassword: {
                        required: true,
                    }
                },

                invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
     //display error alert on form submit    
                },

                errorPlacement: function (label, element) { // render error placement for each input type   
     $('<span class="error"></span>').insertAfter(element).append(label)
                    var parent = $(element).parent('.input-with-icon');
                    parent.removeClass('success-control').addClass('error-control');  
                },

                highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
     
                },

                unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change done by hightlight
                    
                },

                success: function (label, element) {
     var parent = $(element).parent('.input-with-icon');
     parent.removeClass('error-control').addClass('success-control'); 
                },
       submitHandler: function(form) {
      
            var username=$("#txtusername").val();
            var password=$("#txtpassword").val();
            var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
            

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "login.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                        success: function(data){
                        if(data) {
                            window.location.href = "index.php";
                        } else {
                            
                            $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span>                           Invalid username and password. ");
                        }
                    }

                });
            
         
    }
            }); 

});
```

```html
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.
$username = ($_POST['username']));
  $password = ($_POST['password']));
.
.
.
.
.
}
else
{
echo "Doesnt Work";
}

?>

.
.
.

<form id="login-form" class="login-form" action="#" method="post">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-10">
      <div id="error"></div>
            <label class="form-label">Username</label>
            <div class="controls">
    <div class="input-with-icon  right">                                       
     <i class=""></i>
     <input type="text" name="txtusername" id="txtusername" class="form-control">                                 
    </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
    <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-10">
            <label class="form-label">Password</label>
            <span class="help"></span>
            <div class="controls">
    <div class="input-with-icon  right">                                       
     <i class=""></i>
     <input type="password" name="txtpassword" id="txtpassword" class="form-control">                                 
    </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-cons pull-right" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
          </div>
    </form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [documention](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) of data sent to the server. You can use object to send your `data`. In the link above, there are some examples how to send data to server.

```
var dataString = {username: username, password: password}
```